# Batch clip feature class to preserve area field

Tags: arcpy, error-000210

I have a large land cover map in a geodatabase, that I want to batch clip by defined catchments (about 63 polygons). The output files are named based on a field in the "clipper" (sys.argv[2]) called Watershed (currently a hard coded portion of my script).

The script below works if I run it on a shapefile, and point the outputs to an empty folder.
Ideally, I want to run this on a feature class, and point the outputs to a geodatabase using ArcMap9.3, however, I get the following error code: 000210: Cannot create output .

Does anyone have any suggestions?  I have full permissions on my machine, and path directories are correct, so I'm not sure why I'm getting this particular error.

```
# Parameter list for ArcToolbox
#                                   Parameter Properties
#           Display Name            Data type           Type        Direction   MultiValue
#   argv[1] Output workspace        Workspace           Required    Input       No
#   argv[2] Layer used to Clip      Feature Class       Required    Input       No
#   argv[3] Layer to be clipped     Feature Class       Required    Input       No
#   argv[4] prefix for file name    String          Required    Input       No
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

#Import system modules
import sys
import string
import os
import arcgisscripting

# Create the Geoprocessor object
gp = arcgisscripting.create(9.3)

# Load required toolboxes...
gp.AddToolbox("C:/Program Files/ArcGIS/ArcToolbox/Toolboxes/Analysis Tools.tbx")

# Designate a workspace for cliped vector data
gp.workspace = sys.argv[1]

# Assign variables to be processed...
clipper = sys.argv[2] # feature used to clip vector data
vector = sys.argv[3] # vector data to be clipped and then rasterized
suffix = sys.argv[4] # file naming convention prefix

# Search cursor sequence...
rows = gp.SearchCursor(clipper)
row = rows.Next()
feat = row.Shape # used as the clip_features in the Clip_analysis (clipper input must have a field called "Index_Key", which is used as the file name of each output)
while row:
    n = str(row.Watershed) # assign a variable for the processing message based on a field
    print "clipping to: " +n # tells you what grid was clipped
    # Clip_analysis <in_features> <clip_features> <out_feature_class> {cluster_tolerance}
    gp.Clip_analysis(vector, feat, str(row.Watershed)+"_"+str(suffix)+".shp", "") #update str if necessary
    row=rows.next()

# reset the array...
del rows
del gp
```

Comment: So you have the geodatabase pre-created when you run the script? Have you shut down ArcCatalog and ArcMap and then run the script? I'm wondering if this is a geodatabase lock issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your while loop, it is trying to output a shapefile.

You can see this by the string the script tries to construct:

`gp.Clip_analysis(vector, feat, str(row.Watershed)+"_"+str(suffix)+".shp", "")`

Change to either:

`gp.Clip_analysis(vector, feat, str(row.Watershed)+"_"+str(suffix), "")` or
`gp.Clip_analysis(vector, feat, str(n)+"_"+str(suffix), "")`

I think that should get it a little farther.

Comment: I will suggest to change above line to:                    gp.Clip_analysis(vector, feat, str(row.getValue(Watershed)+"_"+str(suffix), "")