# ArcPy 10.0 iterate through shapefile1 clip shapefile2 to shapefile1's polygons

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcpy, arcmap, python-2.7

I know that this question has been answered several times before, but for some reason I can't get this script to run... So I was hoping someone could point out where I'm going wrong.

I have two shapefiles, shapefile 1 has polygon boundaries and shapefile 2 has a single polygon that overlaps the firsts polygonal boundaries.

I would like to clip shapefile 2 according to each polygon of shapefile 1.

I have seen several sites and examples, but for some reason I must be overlooking a detail in getting this to work

Some of the examples I've seen are:
[How to Batch Clip in ArcGIS Desktop 10 using Python/ArcPy?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/19928/how-to-batch-clip-in-arcgis-desktop-10-using-python-arcpy)

[Batch clip feature class to preserve area field](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/18381/batch-clip-feature-class-to-preserve-area-field)

[Clipping buffers to census tracts](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/59172/clipping-buffers-to-census-tracts)

```
import arcpy
arcpy.env.workspace = "path\\to\\workspace\\MaintenanceDivisions"
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput=True
#variables
md = "MaintenanceDivisions.shp"
out = arcpy.CreateUniqueName( "clipped.shp" ) 
mfp = "dissolved.shp"
try:
    #clip polygons from selected area
    rows = arcpy.SearchCursor(md)
    row = rows.next()
    for row in rows:
        feat = row.Shape
        arcpy.Clip_analysis([mfpd], feat, out, "")
        row = rows.next()   
except arcpy.ExecuteError as e:
    print(e)    
del rows
```

Comment: Why not just use one of the overlay tools such as Intersect or Union?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can see your syntax is off in the clip command.  I would take the following approach:

```
import arcpy, os

outws = r'C:\temp'
poly_single = r'C:\temp\poly_single.shp'  # The polygon to be clipped
poly_multi = r'C:\temp\poly_multi.shp'    # The clip features

rows = arcpy.SearchCursor(poly_multi)

count = 0     # Start a counter to name output polygons
for row in rows: # Loop through individual features of "poly_multi"
    out_poly = os.path.join(outws, "out_poly" + str(count))  # Assemble the output poly name and path
    arcpy.Clip_analysis(poly_single, row.Shape, out_poly)
    count = count + 1

# Clean up...Not necessary using "with" statement used in arcpy.da module 
del row
del rows
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import arcpy

p1 = "C:/p1.shp" #Multiple polygons
p2 = "C:/p2.shp" #Single polygon

with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(p1, ("FID", "SHAPE@")) as p1_cur:                  
    with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(p2, "SHAPE@") as p2_cur:                   
        for r2 in p2_cur:
            for r1 in p1_cur:
                intersect = r2[0].intersect(r1[1], 4)
                arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(intersect, "C:/{0}.shp".format(r1[0]))
```